# Count the different variables in an array in my document

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying out rethinkDB and playing around with some query to see if it could fit by use case. So far, so good. However, I have a question regarding reQL.

For example in this case I store analytics events in rethinkDB such as:

```
[{
  "userId": "abdf213",
  "timestamp": "Sat Jan 17 2015 00:32:20 GMT+00:00",
  "action": "Page"
},
{
  "userId": "123abc",
  "timestamp": "Sat Jan 17 2015 00:42:20 GMT+00:00",
  "action": "Track"
},
{
  "userId": "abdf213",
  "timestamp": "Sat Jan 17 2015 00:45:20 GMT+00:00",
  "action": "Track"
},
{
  "userId": "123abc",
  "timestamp": "Sat Jan 17 2015 00:44:20 GMT+00:00",
  "action": "Page"
},
{
  "userId": "123abc",
  "timestamp": "Sat Jan 17 2015 00:48:20 GMT+00:00",
  "action": "Page"
}]
```

I'd like the end result of my query to look like this:

```
{
  "group": "123abc",
  "reduction": {
    "Page": 2,
    "Track": 1
  }
},
{
  "group": "abdf213",
  "reduction": {
    "Page": 1,
    "Track": 1
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that the action name are not known in advance.

TBH, I'm not quite sure how to achieve this with ReQL.

Right now I have this query (using the data explorer):

```
r.db('test').table('events').group('userId').map(function(event) {
  return event('action')
})
```

which return doc like this one:

```
{
  "group":  "-71omc5zdgdimpuveheqs6dvt5q6xlwenjg7m" ,
  "reduction": [
  "Identify" ,
  "Page" ,
  "Track"
  ]
}
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction here?

Cheers,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```html
r.table('events').group('userId').map(function(event) {
  return r.object(event('action'), 1);
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.merge(b.keys().map(function(key) {
    return [key, a(key).default(0).add(b(key))];}).coerceTo('object'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
r.table("events").group("userId", "action").count().ungroup()
                 .group(r.row("group")(0))
                 .map([r.row("group")(1), r.row("reduction")])
                 .coerceTo("object")
```

ReQL doesn't support nesting groups, but you can group by multiple fields at the same time and then performing further grouping on the output.

Comment: It is a valid answer (and cleaner) however your query is 6x slower than @user3595332. and I'm not sure why.  Your query average time is 1.2s on my laptop while the other is 200ms...